# How to get response from wcf services in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am creating Wcf web service in ASP.net. For Printing response  from web service i am using  Context.Response.Write(); but it is showing compile time error to me. please any one tell me how to print the response from WCF web servce.

my code:

```
 public void getdata()
        {
            try
            {


                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con2"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select CircleID, CircleName from Circle", con);
                con.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
                // DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                JavaScriptSerializer JSSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> DtRows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> newrow = null;

                //Code to loop each row in the datatable and add it to the dictionary object
                foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    newrow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        newrow.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), drow[col]);
                    }
                    DtRows.Add(newrow);
                }
                con.Close();

                if (DtRows.Count > 0)
                {



                    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                    Context.Response.Write(JSSerializer.Serialize(DtRows));
                }

            }
```

in the above  code   Context.Response.Write  shows "error".

please help me.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @Amit kumar ghosh "Context does not contain a definition for Response error"

Comment: please anyone help me

Comment: Where is the service

Comment: Try to add `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />` in the web.config and add `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]` on the top of the class that implements the service interface.